# Datepart Calculation in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having problem with the datepart calculation in the Where clause of a query. The query returns result without the calculation but nothing if i add the condition.

```
DECLARE @StatusId INT;
SELECT @StatusId = Id FROM company.Status WHERE Name = 'Signed' AND CompanyId = 1;

SELECT FORMAT(CAST(cont.CreatedDate AS DATE), 'MM/dd') AS newDate, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cont.UpdatedDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalSignedLeads
FROM client.testw cont
WHERE cont.CompanyId = 1  
    AND cont.AffiliateId = 1
    AND cont.CreatedDate BETWEEN '7-01-2017' AND '7-09-2017' 
    AND DATEPART(dw, cont.CreatedDate) NOT IN (1, 7) //This causes problem.
    AND cont.StatusId = @StatusId 
GROUP BY CAST(cont.CreatedDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY newDate ;

This is the data above query gives without the datepart condition.  
newDate  TotalSignedLeads
07/08    7
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: No data is returned if following condition is added to query.... AND DATEPART(dw, cont.CreatedDate) NOT IN (1, 7) //This causes problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since you are casting `cont.CreatedDate` as a date in the top of the query, I suspect it's actually a `varchar`... thus you need

```
...
and datepart(weekday, cast(cont.CreatedDate as date)) not in (1,7)
...
```

[bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

If you aren't getting an error, then you don't have any rows which meet that condition. Perhaps your [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql) setting isn't what you think it is.

Also, not sure what `GROUP BY CAST(@StatusId.CreatedDate AS DATE)` is meant to be...

Comment: I tried your solution but still no records. There are rows  meeting the condition in the db. @StatusId.CreatedDate was a typo.Corrected now

Comment: Did you check your DATEFIRST setting? Can you post data that SHOULD be returned?

Comment: Yes...Its set to 7

Comment: This is the data above query gives without the datepart condition.    newDate  TotalSignedLeads
07/08  7

Comment: but what's the actual DATE for that data? Add cont.CreatedDate to the query

Comment: 2017-07-08 00:00:00.000

Comment: Well if DATEFIRST = 7 then the weekday for that date is 7 and thus would be excluded since you used NOT IN (1,7) @TechRon `select datepart(weekday,'2017-07-08')`

Comment: I was doing select datepart(weekday,GETUTCDATE()) which was giving 6 hence the confusion...Pardon me for wasting your time on such a question...5th month into programming

Comment: No worries @TechRon, it's the little things that gets us.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want a query more like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(cont.CreatedDate AS DATE), 'MM/dd') AS newDate, 
       COUNT(cont.UpdatedDate) AS TotalSignedLeads
FROM client.testw cont
WHERE cont.CompanyId = 1 AND
      cont.AffiliateId = 1 AND
      cont.CreatedDate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-09-01' AND
      DATEPART(dw, CAST(cont.CreatedDate AS DATE)) NOT IN (1, 7) AND //This causes problem.
      cont.StatusId = @StatusId 
GROUP BY FORMAT(CAST(cont.CreatedDate AS DATE), 'MM/dd')
ORDER BY newDate ;
```

Changes:

- The dates for comparison are in a standard format, so they should be interpreted correctly.
- The `GROUP BY` uses the same structure as the `SELECT` for the columns.
- The `SUM(CASE)` is replaced by the much simpler `COUNT()`.
- The value for `CreatedDate` is cast as a `DATE`.  To be honest, I'm not sure that will fix any problem, because that should be happening anyway.